# Is it possible to make a shell of CMD online?

Tags: command, cmd, prompt

Is it possible to make a Command Prompt shell, that is accessible over the Internet? So a user could run command prompt online (that still affects their computer)?

Comment: and that would be useful how?

Comment: are you saying you want to type a command on your local machine through a terminal so that it actually executes on your remote server?

Comment: @Jacob can you please clarify your question. Are you trying to access your remote computer using a terminal window from another computer?

Comment: @itsols What I am saying is that I want the website to take in a command (like command prompt would take in a command) then actually execute the command on the user's computer just like command prompt would.

Comment: @Jacob: How would that be a useful feature?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Idk, but I want to know. So please help me, just answer the question.

Comment: @Jacob: I can't see any value in answering a pointless question.

Comment: Take a look at [Secure Shell (ssh)](http://www.openssh.com/). @Wheat, many people want to be able to run commands remotely on their system. That's what telnet, rlogin, and ssh allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly?  No.  However, you could provide an interface to the command line by writing a custom application that took commands and then sent them as system commands.

Even if you could expose your command prompt to the Internet, you wouldn't want to.  It would be a massive security issue for you.  You want to validate commands and the person sending the commands before you allow the commands to be executed.

For how to actually execute commands from C#, here is a forum that has more information:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1222442.aspx/1?how+to+run+command+prompt+commands+from+c+programming